# Compilation of OpenCV program with version higher than 0x240

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to compile an OpenCV program where there is the header :

```
#include <mrpt/otherlibs/do_opencv_includes.h>
#if (MRPT_OPENCV_VERSION_NUM>=0x240) && MRPT_HAS_OPENCV_NONFREE
#   include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
#endif
```

It require a version of OpenCV higher that 0x240.
I installed the OpenCV3 in my computer and now I have two versions of Open CV one lower that  0x240 and the other one is 3.0. When executing the program, it doesn't recognize the version 3.0. 
What should I do ?

Thanks,

Younès

Answer (score 0):

Building MRPT against OpenCV 3.0.0 has been very recently fixed in the `master` branch on [GitHub](https://github.com/MRPT/mrpt), so if you get the code from there it should work now.